# Is there a way to await an async v-model value without using a watcher?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs3

Right now I'm fetching `asynchronous data` from `child components` like so inside the `parent`:

```
<template layout="backend/cms-layout">
  <div id="cms-gallery-create" class="cms-gallery-create">
    <form @submit.prevent="submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <cms-editor v-model="form.body" @emitBody="form.body=$event"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import CmsEditor from '../../components/backend/cms-editor.vue'
import {reactive, watch} from "vue";

const form = reactive({
    body: ''
})

const submit = () => {
    watch(() => form.body, () => {
        // send http request
    })
}
</script>
```

Basically, when `submit` function is run, a `watcher` is waiting for a change in `form.body` to send the http request.

Is there a more elegant way to get `form.data` from the child which is `asynchronous`, other than using a watcher? I was hoping for something like `v-model:await`.

---

Comment: you can give a try to access child component axios response by using reference `ref="childComponent"` and then in parent inside submit event you can access like `this.$refs.childComponent.getFormData`

Comment: `v-model="form.body" @emitBody="form.body=$event"` looks wrong to me. `v-model` already updates `form.body` so why would you need `@emitBody` to also update it? The `watch` inside `submit()` seems like another misuse to me, but there's not enough context in the question to determine the motivations for these odd calls. A better design pattern can be suggested if you clarify with a complete example of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-model` is just a shorthand for binding a reactive variable (in your case `body`) while also updating that variable with an event.

Since you want to respond to that event, I'd recommend you don't use `v-model` and instead manually bind your variable and manually respond the event:

```
<cms-editor :model-value="form.body" @update:model-value="handleForm" />
```

```
async function handleForm(event) {
  form.body = event.target.value;
  // code for sending HTTP request
}
```

The syntax for manually binding v-model is [in the docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html).